# Search string for specific characters and embed it with code

Tags: c#, string

My previous question was closed, because it was mentioned that similar question was already asked, and answered. I was trying to find something like that, but I can't, so I will try to give more details.

I have a file which I am reading line by line.
In every line I am searching for specific phrase: `"see {number}."` or `"See {number}."`

**For example:**

```
see 112.
See 4.
etc.
```

The problem here is that I can't hardcore that specific phrase because I need to found different strings, which I just know starts with "see" followed by any "number", finished by dot.
At first I thought it would be best to use some kind of regular expression. But I am a little worry about performance.

Anyway after I will establish that I need to embed that in code.
Adding specific tag before and after string.
So for example when I found "see 112." i want to replace it with `<link={found_number}>see 112.</link>` for example: `<link=112>see 112.</link>`

I would be grateful for any suggestions, how to achieve that.

Comment: This seems ideal for a RegEx & for anything less than very large amounts of text I would not anticipate any performance issues - have you verified there are such issues?

Comment: The problem is I can't figured out syntax for whole document. There is no problem with single entry, but when I guess there could be around ~100 such entries, I am not sure how to detect all of them, take value found from them, and then replace it.

Comment: There is a `Replace()` method that will do it all: `string result = Regex.Replace(input_text, @"\b(see) (\d+)", @"<link=$2>$1 $2.</link>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);`

Comment: Please show what you have so far so we can see where it's not working. Where is the code that's reading the file? How are you currently parsing the lines? You can use `IndexOf()` to get the index of the word `"see"`, and again to find the `.`. You could then try to parse the text between those into an integer using `int.TryParse`. But if you don't show us what you have, we can't really see what's wrong.

Comment: @AlexK. thank you, that's what I was looking for. You should submit as a answer.